# How to configure container when sub dependencies are determined at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-container

Using Unity, how do I configure the container such that the second-level dependencies are decided at runtime?  For example, I have a class where I am injecting a processor instance via constructor injection.  The processor class has a formatter and a sender.  Depending on runtime conditions the formatter and the sender are identified, but the injection of the processor which needs the formatter and sender has already been injected.

Consider the following...

**Model Definition**

```
namespace ClassLibrary1.Models
{
    public interface IModel
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model : IModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Sender Definition**

```
using ClassLibrary1.Models;

namespace ClassLibrary1.Senders
{
    public interface ISender
    {
        void Send(IModel Model, string FormattedContent);
    }

    public class Sender1 : ISender
    {
        public void Send(IModel Model, string FormattedContent)
        {
            // do whatever
        }
    }

    public class Sender2 : ISender
    {
        public void Send(IModel Model, string FormattedContent)
        {
            // do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

**Formatter Definition**

```
using ClassLibrary1.Models;

namespace ClassLibrary1.Formatters
{
    public interface IFormatter
    {
        string Format(IModel Model);
    }

    public class FormatterA : IFormatter
    {
        public string Format(Models.IModel Model)
        {
            return "aaaaaaaaa";
        }
    }

    public class FormatterB : IFormatter
    {
        public string Format(Models.IModel Model)
        {
            return "bbbbbbbbb";
        }
    }
}
```

Processor Definition

```
using ClassLibrary1.Formatters;
using ClassLibrary1.Models;
using ClassLibrary1.Senders;

namespace ClassLibrary1.Processors
{
    public interface IProcessor
    {
        string Process(int Id);
    }

    public class Processor : IProcessor
    {
        private IFormatter formatter;
        private ISender sender;

        public Processor(IFormatter formatter, ISender sender)
        {
            this.formatter = formatter;
            this.sender = sender;
        }

        public string Process(int Id)
        {
            IModel model = new Model() {Id = Id, Name = "test"};
            var formattedText = this.formatter.Format(model);
            this.sender.Send(model, formattedText);
            return formattedText;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the consumer...

```
using ClassLibrary1.Processors;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Test
    {
        private IProcessor processor;

        public Test(IProcessor processor)
        {
            this.processor = processor;
        }

        public void MyMethod()
        {
            // IF DAY OF THE WEEK IS MONDAY, THEN RESOLVE SENDER TO SENDER1 AND FORMATTER TO FORMATTERA
            // IF DAY OF THE WEEK IS TUESDAY, THEN RESOLVE SENDER TO SENDER1 AND FORMATTER TO FORMATTERB
            // IF DAY OF THE WEEK IS WEDNESDAY, THEN RESOLVE SENDER TO SENDER2 AND FORMATTER TO FORMATTERA
            // IF DAY OF THE WEEK IS THURSDAY, THEN RESOLVE SENDER TO SENDER2 AND FORMATTER TO FORMATTERB
            this.processor.Process(123);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [RegisterFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee650210.aspx) is likely what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is something you can ask unity to do.  I would use some sort of factory maybe to do the logic to return the right formatter and sender.  This factory could then be injected into your processor class.

```
public interface IFormatter
{
    string Format(Model model);
}
public interface IFormatterA : IFormatter
{
}
public interface IFormatterB : IFormatter
{
}
public interface IFormatterFactory
{
    IFormatter Create();
}
public class FormatterFactory : IFormatterFactory
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;
    public FormatterFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IFormatter Create()
    {
        if (Monday)
            return _container.Resolve<IFormatterA>();
        if(Tuesday)
            return _container.Resolve<IFormatterB>();
    }
}
```

Comment: A factory is the way to go in these situations.  However, I wouldn't inject the container into the factory as it tightly couples the factory solution to the container.  Instead, I would either inject both `IFormatter`s into the factory and return the correct one or inject multiple `Func<IFormatter>`s (if Unity sees a `Func<T>` and it can resolve T it will automatically inject a `Func<T>`) so only the appropriate `IFormatter` is instantiated.

Comment: didn't know that unity would inject a Func<T> which I assume is a wrapper for _container.Resolve<T>().  That sounds neat!!

Comment: See [Automatic Factories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec32) which relates to this topic.